# In one version of the Modularity Theorem, what does "arise from modular forms" mean?

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, algebraic-geometry, modular-forms

One version of Modularity Theorem says that

> The elliptic curves with rational $j$-values arise from modular forms.

Where

$$j(\tau)=1728\frac{g_2^3(\tau)}{\Delta(\tau)}$$

I know every terminology in the statement, but I don't know what "arise from" mean. Can anyone tell me?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The construction of Eichler-Shimura associates to a weight $2$ newform $f\in S_2(\Gamma_0(N))$ (trivial character) an abelian variety quotient $A_f$ of the modular Jacobian $J_0(N)$ (Jacobian of $X_0(N)$). Explicitly one takes the kernel $I_f$ of the homomorphism from the Hecke algebra to $\mathbf{C}$ determined by $f$ and then $A_f$ is $J_0(N)/I_fJ_0(N)$ (defined appropriately). The dimension of this abelian variety is equal to the degree over $\mathbf{Q}$ of the number field generated by the Hecke eigenvalues of $f$. In particular, if the Fourier coefficients of $f$ are rational, $A_f$ is an elliptic curve. The meaning of the boxed statement is that every elliptic curve over $\mathbf{Q}$ is isogenous to $A_f$ for some $f\in S_2(\Gamma_0(N))^{\mathrm{new}}$ with rational Fourier coefficients and some integer $N$ (which can actually be taken to be the conductor of $E$).

Comment: well. I will learn more to understand what you are saying...

Comment: If integrating $f(z)dz$ on the homology of $X_0(N)$ gives a lattice then so does integrating $(f(z)+\frac{a}{b} f(cz)) dz$ so we can replace newform by eigenfunction of Hecke operators $T_p,p\nmid N$. For the dimension of $A_f$ we can say the finite dimension of $S_2(\Gamma_0(N))$ implies the Hecke algebra is finitely generated so $I_f J_0(N)$ is well-defined subvariety. Also Hecke operators have integers entries on the homology thus on modular forms in some basis, so $K_f$ is a finite extension and $2i\pi f(z)dz=w(j(z),j(Nz)) d(1/j(z))$ for some $w\in K_f(X,Y)$